# Database connection from Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, oracle, visual-studio-2005, oracle10g

How to connect Visual Studio 2005 with oracle 10g?

Answer (score 1):

Check these:

- [Oracle Data Access Components](http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/tech/windows/odpnet/index.html)
- [Running VS 2005, Oracle 10g client and ODT/ODP.Net](http://daveclarkesblog.blogspot.com/2007/07/running-vs-2005-oracle-10g-client-and.html)
- [oracle connection with visual studio 2005 with c#](http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread114250.html)